# Unable to cast Dictionary<string, string> to class descended from Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, casting

I have a complex data structure with nested dictionaries.
Something like this: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>`
which is not readable at all, so my thought was to create classes descending from Dictionary<.., ..> and improve readability by casting the dictionaries to these classes. Something like this:

```
private class MyKeyValues : Dictionary<string, string> {}
private class MyAssetKeyValues : Dictionary<string, MyKeyValues> {}
```

My problem boils down to the code below which compiles, but fails runtime with a casting exception.
Why is what i'm trying to do failling? And is there a workaround to improve the readability of those nested dictionaries?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, string> { }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "DummyKey1", "DummyVal1"},
                { "DummyKey2", "DummyVal2"},
            };
            var myDictionary = (MyDictionary)dictionary;
            foreach (var key in myDictionary.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key}, Val: {myDictionary[key]}");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to cast to `MyDictionary` from an object which *isn't* a `MyDictionary`. Put it this way - would you expect this code to work? `object o = new object(); string text = (string) o;`? If you did, what would you expect that string to look like? Your example is just a more complex example of the same thing. If you want to be able to cast to `MyDictionary`, you need to create an instance of `MyDictionary` (or a subclass). Personally I would discourage this general approach, mind you - creating an inheritance hierarchy just to avoid long names isn't usually a good long-term approach IMO

Comment: That doesn't mean you need to avoid abstractions entirely, of course - just that it's worth considering *more* abstraction, instead of just deriving a class from `Dictionary<string, string>`. Think about *composing* a dictionary instead, and providing a higher-level abstraction which is specific to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with this - almost every time I see someone inherit from `Dictionary` (or `List` for that matter!) it's almost *always* the wrong thing to do. Inheritance implies an `is-a` link, whereas what you almost always want is a `has-a` relationship. Composition. Your class `MyAssetKeyValues` should *contain* a `Dictionary` not *inherit from* `Dictionary`.

Then, all this becomes simple. You class might take a `Dictionary` as a constrictor argument, allowing you to construct one from a `Dictionary`

```
private class MyKeyValues 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> dict;

    public MyKeyValues(Dictionary<string,string> dict){ this.dict = dict; }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "DummyKey1", "DummyVal1"},
    { "DummyKey2", "DummyVal2"},
};
var myDictionary = new MyKeyValues(dictionary);
```

Note that you can still make your class *behave* like a dictionary by implementation detail. And you can nest these as much as you like:

```
private class MyAssetKeyValues {
    private readonly  Dictionary<string, MyKeyValues> dict;

    // .... //
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec. I implemented your suggestion and it helped a lot with the readability.

Comment: @AllanSimonsen great! I'm glad it helped.